# Insert and update doesn't change database (sdf)

Tags: c#, database, sql-server-ce

I have a problem with saving data to database named `Settings.sdf`. I have few files:

```
- Settings.sdf
- SettingsDataSet.xsd
 - SettingsDataSet.Designer.cs
 - SettingsDataSet.xsc
 - SettingsDataSet.xss
```

If I tried use `UPDATE` or `INSERT INTO` queries I would not update my database (`Settings.sdf`), only change data in cache file (whatever and wherever it is). I'm using correctly all `SqlCeCommands`. For example:

```
string conString = "Data Source=Settings.sdf";
con = new SqlCeConnection(conString);
con.Open();
...
using (SqlCeCommand com = new SqlCeCommand("UPDATE Settings SET [Value] = (@loc) WHERE [Key] = 'Location'", con))
{
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@loc", device.Location);
    com.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
...
con.Close();
```

How manage this problem? Why this command doesn't update directly my database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can adjust your database path, you must set full path:

1. Adjust with:

   ```
   string conString = "Data Source=" + Path.Combine(Your full path,"Settings.sdf");`
   ```
2. Add `;` at the end of your query

```
using (SqlCeCommand com = new SqlCeCommand("UPDATE Settings SET [Value] = (@loc) WHERE [Key] = 'Location';", con))
{
...
}
```

Comment: add ; in the end of your query

Comment: I'm using WPF so it's bad to add Windows.Forms references. I can't use Application.StartupPath. The ';' at the end of the query is not necessery, but I've tried to use it and still nothing.

Comment: I have the same problem, but I added `;` and `using (SqlCeCommand com = new SqlCeCommand("UPDATE Settings SET [Value] = (@loc) WHERE [Key] = 'Location';", con))
{
...
}` but It doesn't work... Another idea?

Answer (score 0):

the changed maded in the sdf file in debug directory but when you run again the sdf will be created again, remove the create always and test again